# Python Starting Java application with subprocess:Invalid maximum heap size

Tags: python, java, subprocess, heap-memory

I am trying to start a Java application with Python using the subprocess module. I am not new to Python but I am new to the subprocess module.  When I try to run this code:

```
import subprocess as sp
proc = sp.Popen(["java", "-Xmx1536M -Xms1536M", "-jar /home/bekk/MServer/ForgeBukkit/MCPC.jar"],stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,)
```

The command:

```
java -Xmx1536M -Xms1536M -jar /home/bekk/MServer/ForgeBukkit/MCPC.jar
```

runs correctly when typed into a terminal, so I know that it can work.
It seems to be a problem with running it from Python. Any thoughts on what my problem might be?

Comment: When you try to run that code, …, _what_?  You started a sentence, but didn't finish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `"-Xmx1536M -Xms1536M"` as a single argument.

That's not equivalent to this shell command:

```
java -Xmx1536M -Xms1536M -jar /home/bekk/MServer/ForgeBukkit/MCPC.jar
```

… but to this one:

```
java '-Xmx1536M -Xms1536M' -jar /home/bekk/MServer/ForgeBukkit/MCPC.jar
```

So, Java will get that `'-Xmx1536M -Xms1536M'` as its `argv[1]`, instead of getting one flag in `argv[1]` and the next in `argv[2]`. And it will interpret that one giant flag arg as you trying to set `mx` to `'1536M -Xms1536M'`, which is not a valid maximum heap size.

To fix it, put each argument in its own string in the list:

```
["java", "-Xmx1536M", "-Xms1536M", "-jar", "/home/bekk/MServer/ForgeBukkit/MCPC.jar"]
```